# jquery DataTable conditional formating in R

Tags: jquery, r

I'd like to implement a conditional formating. E.g.

```
library(DT)

datatable(mtcars, options = list(
  fnRowCallback = JS(
    "function ( row, data, index ) {",
    "if ( data[3] > 130 ) {",
        "$(data[3]).css('background-color', '#078DC6');",
      "}",
    "else {",
    "$(data[3]).css('background-color', '#FFDE00');",
      "}",
    "}")))
```

Here I want to change background of rows in terms of `disp` column.How to upgrade this? Right now this code does not change backgorund of rows at all.

Comment: @Fergoso It is some specific solution of  `R package` implementing datables.More here.http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css need to be applied to the row, not the data, so you can try something like this:

```
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars, options = list(
  fnRowCallback = JS(
    "function ( row, data, index ) {",
    "if ( data[2] > 130 ) {",
    "$(row).css('background-color', '#078DC6');",
    "}",
    "else {",
    "$(row).css('background-color', '#FFDE00');",
    "}",
    "}")))
```

Also, array indexes start at 0 in JS.